# ubuntu 16.10 konsole is very slow connecting to gb.archive.ubuntu.com

Tags: apt, kubuntu, kde, 16.10, ipv6

Why `apt-get install` is always slow at this line below?

```
0% [Connecting to gb.archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1560:8001::14)]
```

It takes up to 5 to 10 mins sometimes. It just gets stuck there most of time.

For example:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php-pgsql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gyp libjs-inherits libjs-node-uuid libuv1 libuv1-dev linux-headers-4.8.0-22 linux-headers-4.8.0-22-generic linux-image-4.8.0-22-generic linux-image-extra-4.8.0-22-generic
  node-abbrev node-ansi node-ansi-color-table node-archy node-async node-block-stream node-combined-stream node-cookie-jar node-delayed-stream node-forever-agent node-form-data
  node-fstream node-fstream-ignore node-github-url-from-git node-glob node-graceful-fs node-gyp node-inherits node-ini node-json-stringify-safe node-lockfile node-lru-cache
  node-mime node-minimatch node-mkdirp node-mute-stream node-node-uuid node-nopt node-normalize-package-data node-npmlog node-once node-osenv node-qs node-read
  node-read-package-json node-request node-retry node-rimraf node-semver node-sha node-sigmund node-slide node-tar node-tunnel-agent node-underscore node-which
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  php7.0-pgsql
The following NEW packages will be installed
  php-pgsql php7.0-pgsql
0 to upgrade, 2 to newly install, 0 to remove and 1 not to upgrade.
Need to get 57.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 223 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
0% [Connecting to gb.archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1560:8001::14)]
Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates/main amd64 php7.0-pgsql amd64 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.10.1 [55.8 kB]
Get:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 php-pgsql all 1:7.0+44 [1,920 B]                                                                                     
Fetched 57.7 kB in 8min 4s (118 B/s)                                                                                                                                              
Selecting previously unselected package php7.0-pgsql.                                                                                                                             
(Reading database ... 258311 files and directories currently installed.)                                                                                                          
Preparing to unpack .../0-php7.0-pgsql_7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.10.1_amd64.deb ...                                                                                                      
Unpacking php7.0-pgsql (7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.10.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php-pgsql.
Preparing to unpack .../1-php-pgsql_1%3a7.0+44_all.deb ...
Unpacking php-pgsql (1:7.0+44) ...
Processing triggers for libapache2-mod-php7.0 (7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.10.1) ...
Setting up php7.0-pgsql (7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.10.1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/pgsql.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/pdo_pgsql.ini with new version
Setting up php-pgsql (1:7.0+44) ...
Processing triggers for libapache2-mod-php7.0 (7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.10.1) ...
```

I'm on ubuntu/ kubuntu 16.10.

**EDIT:**

```
$ ping -c4 gb.archive.ubuntu.com
PING gb.archive.ubuntu.com(steelix.canonical.com (2001:67c:1560:8001::11)) 56 data bytes

--- gb.archive.ubuntu.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3056ms
```

vs

```
$ ping6 -c4 gb.archive.ubuntu.com
PING gb.archive.ubuntu.com(steelix.canonical.com (2001:67c:1560:8001::11)) 56 data bytes

--- gb.archive.ubuntu.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3073ms
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
$ which ping
/bin/ping

$ ping -V
ping utility, iputils-s20150815
```

Comment: @DavidFoerster i have added my outputs. please see my edit above. i don't see much difference between them in time. what are they are?

Comment: @DavidFoerster please see my edit 2 above thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately that wasn't very illumination. But it seems you found your answer, so never mind. :-)

Comment: That mirror is up and responding. You should investigate what is wrong with IPv6 connectivity in your network, and fix it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton how do i know my IPv6 connectivity has gone wrong? how do i check and fix it?

Comment: See with `ip -6 addr` if your machine has one or more global IPv6 addresses assigned. You need something starting with `2xxx:`, like `2001:` or `2a02:` (not of interest are those starting with `fe80::`, which are link local, or those starting with `fcxx:` or `fdxx:`, which are a kind of "private" addresses).  If this is correct, try `ip -6 route`, which should show a "`default via`" default route to your router. If this is correct, use `traceroute6 gb.archive.ubuntu.com` to see where packets get lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note: it seems like you are connected to the Ubuntu mirror via `IPv6` which might cause the slow respond

**In order to use `IPv4` only you can use the following methods
 [suggested here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9940/convince-apt-get-not-to-use-ipv6-method):**

> Add `-o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true` when running `apt-get`.
>
> If you want to make the setting persistent just create
>   `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4` and put `Acquire::ForceIPv4
>   "true";` in it:
>
> ```
> echo 'Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4
> ```

**A few links which should help you get a faster mirror:**

**Using GUI**: https://blog.kmonsoor.com/ubuntu-update-apt-get-server-to-use-fastest-mirror/

**Using command line**: http://tuxdiary.com/2015/06/13/find-fastest-ubuntu-mirror-cmdline/

**Using apt-select**: https://github.com/jblakeman/apt-select

Comment: `it seems like you are connected to the ubuntu mirror via IPv6 is it by purpose?` how do I know that? and how can I disable it? I did not set it that way.

Comment: how can I set to use `IPv4` instead?

Comment: This `2001:67c:1560:8001::14` is `IPv6` address

Comment: Try using the GUI (see link in my answer) to set the fastest mirror, and let me know if it solve the problem.

Comment: can i set it to `IPv4` instead?

Comment: @teelou - I've edited my answer and added a suggestion - how to use IPv4 only

Comment: thanks for the edit. i think i will keep it to ipv6. will just add `-o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true` next time for my `apt-get`.

Comment: The interesting question is: Why doesn't it work with IPv6 for you? It looks like your IPv6 connectivity is broken in some way. (If you had no IPv6 uplink at all, `apt` would not even try to connect using IPv6.)

Comment: @Dubu - as you suggested, it is possible that the IPv6 network from the ISP to the ubuntu server is problematic. see the link in my answer for more ideas